# SPI connection in Docker container—permission denied

Tags: python, docker, raspberry-pi, spi

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero W (armv6) and an RFID MFRC522 module. I can use it fine from Python as follows:

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522

reader = SimpleMFRC522()

try:
    id = reader.read()[0]
    print("The ID for this card is:", id)
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

However, I'm now trying to access the device form Docker with no luck. This is my Docker setup:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY controller/requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --index-url=https://www.piwheels.org/simple --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY controller .

CMD ["python", "controller.py"]
```

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  controller:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_controller
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - /lib/modules:/lib/modules
      - /sys:/sys
      - /dev:/dev
    devices:
      - /dev/gpiomem
      - /dev/gpiochip0
      - /dev/ttyAMA0
```

I'm trying to run in privileged mode and to include relevant devices and volumes as advised online. I'm getting the following error though:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/controller.py", line 4, in <module>
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/RPi/GPIO/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from RPi._GPIO import *
ImportError: Error loading shared library ld-linux-armhf.so.3: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/RPi/_GPIO.cpython-39-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so)
```

It could be that this Alpine image is not compatible? I'm using it mainly for its light weight.

Any ideas welcome!

---

### Update

Fixed this issue above as per Klaus D.'s comment below. Needed to install some C libraries:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY controller .

RUN apk add --update --no-cache gcc libc-dev gcompat
RUN pip install --index-url=https://www.piwheels.org/simple --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "controller.py"]
```

However, I'm now getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/controller.py", line 30, in <module>
    reader = SimpleMFRC522()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mfrc522/SimpleMFRC522.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.READER = MFRC522()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mfrc522/MFRC522.py", line 130, in __init__
    self.spi.open(bus, device)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

There's some discussion online about giving users access to SPI (and other GPIO stuff) but haven't managed to get it to work. If I open a terminal inside my running container I can see the following:

```
/usr/src/app #  ls -all /dev/*spi*
crw-rw----    1 nobody   nobody    153,   0 Feb  2 19:24 /dev/spidev0.0
crw-rw----    1 nobody   nobody    153,   1 Feb  2 19:24 /dev/spidev0.1
```

and

```
/usr/src/app #  whoami
root
```

I've tried to change permissions but failed:

```
/usr/src/app # chmod 660 /dev/spidev0.0
chmod: /dev/spidev0.0: Operation not permitted
```

I've also tried `chown`.

Comment: Add `RUN apk add gcompat` to your `Dockerfile_controller`. There might be other missing dependencies.

Comment: Thanks! I've added the following just to be sure: `RUN apk add --update --no-cache gcc gcc-6-base libc6 libgcc1 libc-dev linux-headers gcompat`. The error I was getting is gone. Now I'm facing: `self.spi.open(bus, device) --> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`.

Comment: This is interesting, I'm using the root user inside the container.